# Customize file name of button extension downloads

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I feel a bit silly for asking all these basic questions, but I could not find anything on this. I would like to allow my users to name the file when they click on the 'excel' button for my table. Either the download dialogue opens or another UI pops up where they could type in the name. Is that possible? For now, the name equals the tag of the app.

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(matrix(abs(rnorm(600*40,sd=100)),nrow=600))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  output$view <- DT::renderDataTable(
    DT[,.SD],extensions = c( 'FixedHeader','Buttons'),
      options=list(pageLength=60,fixedHeader = TRUE,dom = 'Bfrtip',buttons = c( 'csv', 'excel'  )))
}) 

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny MWE"),
        DT::dataTableOutput("view")
    ))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: I do not believe this is possible. The file name is parameter in the options see: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/343#issuecomment-239600594, and options are not reactive, so you would have to redraw the table each time the filename was changed.

Comment: But then I can add the filename option somewhere to chose a different name?

Comment: Yes, will post answer when in front of computer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make a reactive `datatable` and then pass that to `renderDataTable`, but it will rerender each time you change the filename:

```
rm(list=ls()) 
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
library(DT)
library(data.table)
DT<-data.table(matrix(abs(rnorm(600*40,sd=100)),nrow=600))

server<-shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dt <- reactive({
    DT::datatable(DT[,.SD],extensions = c( 'FixedHeader','Buttons'),
    options=list(pageLength=60,fixedHeader = TRUE,dom = 'Bfrtip',
                 buttons = list("csv",list(extend='excel',filename=input$filename))))
  })

  output$view <- DT::renderDataTable(
    dt(),server=FALSE
    )
}) 

ui<-shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Shiny MWE"),
  textInput("filename","Enter file name"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("view")
))

runApp(list(ui=ui,server=server))
```

Comment: Thanks in the meantime I switched to Download Handler, also because my app became to slow using the server=FALSE option.